# Currently intern, what to do *now* to negotiate a better salary when being offered permanent position?

Tags: software-industry, salary, internship, negotiation, united-kingdom

### Background

I transitioned into web development. **Because I had no relevant experience, I accepted a 4-month internship** in a company, with the aim of getting tenured. (It was made clear from the beginning by the company that this internship was a way to test me prior offering a permanent position).

I didn't negotiated my internship wages (see [previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/120025/67324)). **I like my current job** and I am keen to stay. I know they would like it too. (I am pre-registered for a company training that is *after* the end of my internship.)

**However, I want a significant raise** (more than twice my current salary) to match what I think I'm worth. (I already received offers in this range — cf. previous question.) I know this means that I must accept to leave the company if we don't find a common ground.

### Question

I'm two months into the internship. Let's assume they'll make me an offer.

Besides doing the best job I can, I am wondering:

> **What could I do *now* to have a better hand when negotiating my salary when being given tenure?**

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I disagree. It's already clear here we're due to negotiate a new contract with new compensation. Date for it is known (a couple of months from now). Even if answers of that question are helpful, they are so because they explain how to prepare for negotiating a raise _in general_. I am expecting answers that focus on the fact I am new in the company, and that are not only targeted towards the actual negotiation (e.g. "try to get along with your peers"…). So imho, these answers are useful and it's great pointing to them — yet I don't think that the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have in hand an active offer that you can sign if the negotiations don't go as well as you would like, you do have all the advantage you need.

Of course you will never show them the offer, you will not even hint at the offer. You will not tell them you have an offer. Showing them the offer will make them think that even if you do accept their upgraded offer you will be leaving the company soon.

You will just negotiate with the evidence of your performance, and how you have proven that you can make a valuable contribution to the company. Document everything now so that you can explain to them why you think you deserve a very large raise.

How does having an active offer help? You know that in the end if you push a little too hard, and they respond with take it or leave it- you can leave it. Most interns aren't in that position, they will either not make a counter proposal, or make one that is easily accepted. You can ask for the salary you want, and then if they counter with a new offer then you can decide to stay or go. If they don't counter, or they only offer a small bump over the initial offer, then you go.

of course if you don't have an active offer, then you risk unemployment and the chance that the expired offer was a fluke and you settle for a salary lower than you want at a third company.